# Find which if any columns contain identical results from a query

Tags: sql

I'm looking to query a large set of data and find which, if any, columns are all comprised of the same value. (For example, all zip codes are identical) I've considered something to the effect of

```
where count(distinct([column])) = 1
```

but I can't figure out how to make that check every single column, or return which column(s) has the identical values.

Example:
Joe, Jane, and John are all being externally selected. I need to find out what characteristics they have in common.

```
Name        Phone        Address       City      State     Zip       Member#
John        1234567890   123 South St  Chicago   IL.       12345     54321
Jane        9876543210   123 South St  New York  NY.       12345     67890
Joe         1239874560   123 North St  Las Vegas NV.       12345     75315
```

So I am trying to create a query that looks at this data and says the only thing they all have in common is the zip code, all are 12345. The fact that there are duplicate addresses doesn't matter because there is more than one unique value in that column. I'm hoping there's a generalized way that doesn't involve me typing in every single column name into the query as the first result (I believe) would have me do.

Comment: It sounds like your schema needs a re-think. If you want to compare a lot of values of the same "type" (zip code), those values should be in different rows.

Comment: I'm trying to find out similarities based on a different query. There's multiple specific sets of data that are being affected by something and I'm trying to find what shared characteristics they have that they're all being affected by the same thing

Comment: The easiest way to do this is to use dynamic sql, you can then set it up to pull a list of columns from the schema, then iterate through them counting distinct. If it find 1 then insert the column name into a table of some type

Comment: I think an example of your schema, a few sample rows, and example output would make your question a lot more clear..

Comment: @Blorgbeard added example data. I'm hoping there's a way that doesn't involve manually typing every column into the case statement like the answer below says, but I suspect that will work if nothing else does.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using aggregation with a `case` statement:

```
select (case when count(distinct col1) = 1 then 'ALL SAME' end) as col1_type,
       (case when count(distinct col2) = 1 then 'ALL SAME' end) as col2_type,
       . . .
from t;
```

If you wanted them as a list, you could do something like this:

```
select concat((case when count(distinct col1) = 1 then concat('col1', ';' else '' end),
              (case when count(distinct col2) = 1 then concat('col2', ';' else '' end),
              . . . 
             ) 
from t;
```

Although `concat()` is ANSI standard, different databases have different ways of expressing this operation.